# NextJS cors error in page but not in API route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, next.js, cors

I have a nextjs application and when I execute a call to fetch a page from an external website if I do it from the backend via an API route everything works fine however when I do it from the frontend side I get a cors error.

This is the code from the API route:

```
async function getPage(url: string) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    // do stuff
}

export async function POST(req: any) {
    const request = await req.json();
    try {
        await getPage(request.url);
        return NextResponse.json({ status: 200 });
    } catch (err: any) {
        console.log(err);
        return NextResponse.json({}, { status: 400, statusText: 'The website does not exist or is currently down.' });
    }
}
```

This is the same code in the frontend that is throwing an error:

```
async function getPage(url: string) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        }
    });
    // do stuff
}

const fetchPageFromSite = async () => {
        await getPage(url);
}
```

I am using the fetchPageFromSite inside a useEffect.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` doesn't belong in a request.

Comment: @jub0bs thanks for that, do you know what could fix the issue?

Comment: Nothing much to add to Mayank's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

CORS must be manage from Back-End (the external website you want to fetch).

Because Back-end of that website need to allow Cross Origin to your page or all (*).

You can find more details about CORS here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

The concept of `CORS` - Cross Origin Resource Sharing - is applicable only on the client side. When you are sending request from the server (`api` route), the `url` you are fetching from doesn't know about the origin or domain of your website. Thus, your call from `api` route works without any errors.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this issue in the client side of my nextjs app? I have tried many different things but none of them work

Comment: If you control the API, you can add cors headers. If it is third party API, you can not do anything about it